# jruby multipart post fails for files larger than 800k or so

Tags: glassfish, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have a jruby application deployed using glassfish-gem with an apache front end.  When I do a form post of a file it fails on files over a certian size, seems to be around 800k.  The error is below if it helps any.

glassfish.yml is generated, no changes from default other than to increase some java memory settings.

I have bypassed apache and gone straight to the app but still have issues.  Enabling threading in rails makes the problem worse.

```
INFO: /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Oct 29 04:54:17 +0000 2010
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Stream closed
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/utils.rb:466:in `parse_multipart'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/request.rb:268:in `parse_multipart'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/request.rb:146:in `POST'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/facebooker-1.0.75/lib/rack/facebook.rb:38:in `call'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.10/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:100:in `call'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.10/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/var/www/LocalHabit/shared/bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.10/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.dev-universal-java/lib/../lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:133:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.dev-universal-java/lib/../lib/rack/handler/grizzly.rb:55:in `call'
:1

Oct 29, 2010 4:54:17 AM com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer flushChannel
FINEST: flushChannel isAsyncHttpWriteEnabled=false bb=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1088 cap=33368]
```

Comment: Do Trinidad or plain Webrick behave any differently? Could be a bug in Glassfish that we may not be able to fix.

Comment: I have benched this for now.  JRuby 1.4.1 works.  Only thing I have found in digging the internet so far is that it may be related to Neo4j.  Also only get the error when using a browser.  I can pound the crap out of it with apache benchmark with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug introduced in jruby version 1.5.1, that is supposedly fixed in 1.5.6, but I misplaced the details on the bug.  It was actually related to a post issue in jruby in general.